# How to have the placeholder in an MUI TextField component slide to the top of the box instead of within the box's border

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create the following text field to look like the following in MUI:

[image]

However, I have the following:

[image]

When I click inside the text field, the placeholder slides to the top and is placed within the border, but I want to make it so that it looks like the first image where the placeholder is at the top left of the box itself.

I am using MUI's `TextField` component: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/

Can someone shed some light on this?

### Here is my code:

#### CustomField.jsx

```
import React from "react"
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles"
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField"

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)(({ width, marginTop }) => ({
  width: width || "343px",
  marginTop: marginTop || "25px",
  "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
    "&:focus-within fieldset": {
      borderColor: "black",
      color: "black",
    },
  },
  "&:focus-within .MuiFormLabel-root": {
    color: "black",
  },
}))

const CustomTextField = ({ label, variant, helperText, value, onChange, disabled, width, marginTop }) => (
  <StyledTextField
    label={label}
    variant={variant}
    helperText={helperText}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    disabled={disabled}
    width={width}
    marginTop={marginTop}
  />
)

export default CustomTextField
```

#### App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
 const handleEmailChange = () => {};
 const email = "user@email.com;

 return (
   <CustomTextField
        label="Phone number or email"
        variant="outlined"
        helperText="Some helper text."
        onChange={handleEmailChange}
        value={email}
      />
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `variant="filled"` rather than `variant="outlined"`.

You can then create a custom component (or override the filled styles in the theme) to include the borders / outlines you need:

```
const FilledOutlinedInputField = styled((props) => (
  <TextField
    {...props}
    InputProps={{
      ...props.InputProps,
      disableUnderline: true,
    }}
    variant="filled" />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  '& .MuiFilledInput-root': {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#FFF' : '#333',
    border: `2px solid ${ theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#F0F0F0' : '#000' }`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create([
      'border-color',
      'background-color',
      'box-shadow',
    ]),
    '&:hover': {
      borderColor: theme.palette.mode === 'light' ? '#08F' : '#FF0',
    },
    '&.Mui-focused': {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      boxShadow: `${alpha(theme.palette.primary.main, 0.25)} 0 0 0 2px`,
      borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
    },
  },
}));
```

There's a working example in the docs with the Reddit-style input field: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#customization